# PHP Web Form Not Sending To Gmail Email

Tags: php, html, email, gmail

I have a php form that I made and when someone fills out the form it works fine with all other email accounts (yahoo, hotmail, @mydomain.com, etc) but when it comes to sending the email to a gmail user, the email never comes through, not even in the spam box.

```
            $from = $email;

            //Testing Below
            //$headers = 'From:noreply@mydomainname.com' . "\r\n"; 
            $headers .= "From: $from \n";
            $headers .= " MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n ";
            $headers .= " Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n ";

            //Mail The Message
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The code above will not send to gmail but will work for all other email accounts. This one (below) will work for gmail but of course then I don't have the option of html in the email.

```
            $headers = 'From:noreply@mydomainname.com' . "\r\n"; 
            //$headers .= "From: $from \n";
            //$headers .= " MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n ";
            //$headers .= " Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n ";

            //Mail The Message
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

So basically when I add the MIME and Content type to the headers variable it wont send to a gmail account.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `mail`, but another mailer instead.

Comment: What other mail options are there in php? I am still fairly new to php .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replied a question not too long ago related to this. It might have to do with the gmail's email filtering, maybe you are getting too high spam score so it's not even getting into the spam folder, this could be caused by not having correct dns configuration / keys and trying to use html at the same time.

I leave a link to the other answer (It's quite long, and not as easy as you would imagine xD):

[PHP and Gmail spam filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274157/php-and-gmail-spam-filter/15341940#15341940)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will look into this and get back to you. It shouldn't be spam issue I wouldn't image because its a new domain name, less then a month old. Would this matter?

Comment: Of course, the newer the domain, the less credibility it has, Sometimes the filters will throw your email into the spam folder, sometimes they will just reject it. So have a look specially to the reverse dns and the DKIM's

Comment: Well, I contact my hosting account provider to see what they could come up with and after chatting with them for a few hours they couldn't help much. I guess I just will have to strip out the html from the emails until I figure this out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a proper concatenation operator:
Change your From line to:

```
$headers .= "From: ".$from;
```