# sending emails through custom made contact form

Tags: php, html, email, smtp, phpmailer

I'm looking for some general advice with regards to sending emails through a contact form on my website.  I am using PHP Mailer and sending through Gmail SMTP but I believe that this is not secure enough.

From what I have researched it seems like an absolute nightmare sending emails and with this in mind, I wonder if there is a plugin that I can use on my custom HTML contact form?  I also understand that services like SendGrid and Mandrill may help but I cannot for the life of me see how I can connect these services to my contact form.

I am sure there are fellow developers out there who have faced the same problems so any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated- before all my hair falls out!

(Edit: pulled from comments) The received email firstly goes into the spam folder (depending on the recipient address) and when I check the recipient email headers it has things like spf=fail. This leads me to believe that it is not fully secure (or at least secure enough). My main concern is that I do not want my domain or IP address to get blacklisted.

Comment: Please define "not secure enough"

Comment: '*but I believe that this is not secure enough.* - Why do you *believe* that?'

Comment: The received email firstly goes into the spam folder (depending on the recipient address)  and when I check the recipient email headers it has things like spf=fail. This leads me to believe that it is not fully secure (or at least secure enough).  My main concern is that I do not want my domain or IP address to get blacklisted :(

Comment: *"when I check the recipient email headers it has things like spf=fail. This leads me to believe that it is not fully secure"* - That means that the server it was sent from, doesn't have an SPF record. Consult https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework for more information on this.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I see that makes more sense.  My main concern is ensuring that my IP address/domain are not blacklisted, with your knowledge do you believe that sending emails via the contact form through PHP Mailer and Gmail SMTP is enough to avoid this from happening?

Comment: @Coder See this one also [Bypass Gmail's spam filter (mails sent with PHP from a shared host](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15274157/1415724). Which if the question using the first possible duplicate is to be closed with, should also be added to the list, IMHO. Email however and in this day and age, is not 100% failproof/foolproof even with a valid SPF record.

Comment: (Correction) Per [my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416062/sending-emails-through-custom-made-contact-form#comment93706774_53416062): *"That means that the server it was sent from, doesn't have an SPF record."*, that should have read as *"That means that the server it was sent from, may not have an SPF record."*

Comment: @Coder Do you feel that the references left for the Q&A's answered the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, I would suggest trying to clarify your questions. After you establish your situation, try asking very specific (maybe even numbered) questions that you would like answered. I have done my best to parse out your specific questions and answer them below.

**Q) Are there security concerns using PHPMailer**

A) The answer is no. There is nothing inherently insecure about using this for sending email as long as your configuration and mail server is secure. You should follow best practices, using SSL when possible for your connection to your SMTP server used to send the mail.

**Q) Why am I getting SPF failures when sending emails?**

A) You should start by understanding how SPF works. There is a pretty good write up [available here](https://postmarkapp.com/guides/spf). Basically, SPF was designed to help prevent bad actors from sending emails from their own servers but using domains they do not control. This was rampant with early phishing emails.

Now, from the sounds of it, you are attempting to send your emails using Gmail but you are getting SPF errors. I can only assume this is because you are sending from a custom domain, probably using GSuite. This happens very commonly when you have not configured your domain records correctly for GSuite. You can find more information on how to properly configure your [domain here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en).

I hope this helps. Emails and delivery issues are a tricky thing to get perfect. There are a lot of factors that can impact your deliverability, from configuration issues to simply having poor content in the body of your messages. This all can impact deliverability.

As a side note, I would suggest using a service like [Mail Tester](https://www.mail-tester.com/) to test your outgoing emails. It will help you quickly identify common issues.

Comment: thank you for the above, trying to get my head around this all is a real headache.   Yes, you are correct as I am using a domain that is hosted through GoDaddy - with this in mind will the attached document be relevant?  Sorry if I'm sounding a bit out of my depth with this.

Comment: Absolutely, the link I posted related to GSuite should guide you through setting up the correct records on your domain. Again, I would start by running a test email through Mail Tester so you can have a baseline on your issues and then re-test after you make each change to verify you are moving the right direction. Hope this helps!

Comment: Good answer. Message headers in gmail will tell you important things like the domain & IP it thinks the message came from (which is what matters), and you need to make sure your SPF allows that mail source. Regarding security, make sure you're using latest PHPMailer (and any other packages you use); there was a security issue last week that I released a fix for in 6.0.6.

Comment: @Coder Side note ... I tested sending an email from my GSuite email to Mail Tester when writing this post (couldn't remember if it provided the SPF validation or not) and it turns out whichever Gmail server sent the email is currently on a SORBS blacklist ... So there are always things out of your control :)

Comment: @ShawnLehner  thanks for testing, it really does seem like a very difficult maze to navigate through!